# Google trends in R GTrendsR

Tags: r

I'm trying to use GTrendsR but is not working. This is what I run

```
library(devtools)
#install_bitbucket("GTrendsR", "persican")
library(GTrendsR)
usr = "my gmail"
psw = "my password"
ch = gConnect(usr, psw)

location = "all"
query = "MOOCs"
MOOCs_trends = gTrends(ch, geo = location, query = query)
MOOCs_trends$SearchInfo
```

Everything seems to work but the last line gives me "NULL"

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there's an error in the package where they aren't naming the columns in the dataframe.  I ran the same code and get

```
> names(MOOCs_trends)
[1] ""    ""    ""    ""    "GEO"
```

But when you do:

```
>head(MOOCs_trends)
[[1]]
                   Week moocs
1   2004-01-04 - 2004-01-10     0
2   2004-01-11 - 2004-01-17     0
3   2004-01-18 - 2004-01-24     0
```

It works like it should.  So the data is coming back.  A short term fix would be to access the list with numeric indices.  Just do:

```
> MOOCs_trends[[1]]
```

etc... to access the different slots of data.  It will take a quick code fix I'm sure to get the names right.  Alternatively you could add them yourself, but I'd suggest waiting for a code fix so future scripts don't break.

Comment: Thanks! I have another questions about how to plot that, but I will ask it later after trying for a while.